# What happens if I try to send an empty UDP packet through a DatagramChannel but the underling socket buffer is full?

Tags: java, sockets, udp, real-time, nio

I must be missing something but how can I tell if my empty UDP packet was sent through the DatagramChannel send method? If it returns ZERO bytes, does it mean my empty packet was sent or does it mean the underlying socket buffer was full?

From the API:

> The number of bytes sent, which will be either the number of bytes
>   that were remaining in the source buffer when this method was invoked
>   or, if this channel is non-blocking, may be zero if there was
>   insufficient room for the datagram in the underlying output buffer.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html#send(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20java.net.SocketAddress)

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8013175

Answer (score 2):

If you're in blocking mode, it means the zero-length datagram was transferred to the socket send buffer. If you're in non-blocking mode, it's a tossup, but you could resolve it by testing beforehand whether the channel is writable, with a selector.

It could also mean that nothing happened at all, depending on the state of the bug you mention in your comment.

Comment: Weird. Your idea sounds great. If the channel is writable it means I have space in the underlying write socket buffer. Question is: Do I have space for at least an empty packet!????????? That bug is not a bug but a api enhancement.

Comment: Well if the current status is that you can't send empty datagrams at all, the whole question is moot.

Comment: I think you can, you can't just know from the send if it was sent or not, but if you are in a OP_WRITE you have good chances to send a zero-byte packet. Not sure if the headers go into the underlying socket buffer as well.

Comment: Your bug report says you can't: 'This is not a bug, rather this is just a limitation of the API that the write methods cannot be used to send a 0-byte datagram. If there is a big need for this then it will require a bit of investigation as to how to fit it into the API.'

Comment: Which means that the only way to send a zero-length datagram is with a `DatagramPacket`.